# how to set multipart "withname" with dictionary in swift?

Tags: swift

I want to send the images to the server with multipart form. Normal 
    image uploading is working with the multipart but facing the 
    problem is when I need to set `withname` with array inside dictionary.

```
  alamofireManager.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

            for i in 0..<images.count {

                let imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(images[i])!

                    multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "fileUpload",fileName: "\(images)i", mimeType: "image/png")

            }
```

Server parameters are like

```
 "documants" : [{
    "documentType" : "Image",
    "fileUpload: "" // multipart data
},{
    "documentType" : "Image",
    "fileUpload: "" // multipart data
}]
```

So how to mention the node name `documents[0].fileUpload` with `withName` using `multipartFormData`?

Comment: Add This Line Also 

    multipartFormData.append("Image".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "documentType")

Answer (score 0):

You can implement 'multipart' in this way...using Swift4.2

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            /* "Authorization": "your_access_token",  in case you need authorization header */
            "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
        ]

        let url = try! URLRequest(url: baseURL, method: .post, headers: headers)

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(img, withName: "file", fileName: imgName, mimeType: "\(fileType ?? "jpg")")
        }, with: url) {  result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseString { response in
 switch (response.response?.statusCode)
                    {
                        case 200: //The request was fulfilled
                            print("Network - HandShaking Successfull...!!!")
                            debugPrint(response)
                    }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
 }
```

Hope you will get idea of 'multipart'...!!!